Is there a way to reset appplication usage data statistics gathered by Android?
Through the PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS permission (in the manifest, and granted in the Settings) and the APIs available in android.app.usage (link) an Android app can gather statistics about the usage of any other app in the system.
Short of a factory reset of the phone, is there a way to reset the apps usage statistics, in order to test my code? I'm specifically talking about the usage statistics, not the network/data ones.
